# Using SQL FOR XML PATH, how can I achieve the following formatted XML output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, for-xml, for-xml-path

The scope of this project is much larger than this one question. I've been tasked with a project and I'll not bore you with the intimate details. Ultimately what I'm needing to do is get the data out of the database and into XML so I can convert to JSON and create a simple web app that will allow me to parse and format the data in way that will meet the customer's needs.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this is the path I've settled on..

I have about 46,000 records dumped into a Temp Table. To Give you an idea of how this data is structured running the following query:

```
SELECT 
    TransactionID,
    OwnerID,  
    Date, 
    TransactionType,
    ChargeCode, 
    Description, 
    DebitAmount
FROM #OwnerHistoryTemp
WHERE OwnerID = '11111111'
```

Returns this:

```
TransactionID   OwnerID     Date        TransactionType ChargeCode  Description         DebitAmount
28727           11111111    2014-12-01  E               A1          APPLY CHARGES       210.00  
28728           11111111    2014-12-03  C               A1          DB11111111          210.00  
28729           11111111    2015-01-01  E               A1          APPLY CHARGES       183.37
```

What I'm looking to do here is use the SQL FOR XML PATH (open to any other suggestions) to output the data like so:

```
<OwnerHistory>
    <OwnerID OwnerID="11111111">
        <Transactions>
            <TransactionID ID="28727">
                <Date>2014-12-01</Date>
                <TransactionType>E</TransactionType>
                <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
                <Description>APPLY CHARGES</Description>
                <DebitAmount>210.00</DebitAmount>
            </TransactionID>
            <TransactionID ID="28728">
                <Date>2014-12-03</Date>
                <TransactionType>C</TransactionType>
                <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
                <Description>DB11111111</Description>
                <DebitAmount>210.00</DebitAmount>
            </TransactionID>
            <TransactionID ID="28729">
                <Date>2015-1-01</Date>
                <TransactionType>E</TransactionType>
                <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
                <Description>APPLY CHARGES</Description>
                <DebitAmount>183.37</DebitAmount>
            </TransactionID>
        </Transactions>
    </OwnerID>
</OwnerHistory>
```

The Query I have, gets me close, but not QUITE there. Because the same OwnerID appears multiple times (once for each TransactionID), running the following query:

```
SELECT 
    OwnerID AS "@OwnerID", 
    TransactionID AS "Transaction/@RecordID", 
    Date AS "Transaction/Date", 
    TransactionType AS "Transaction/TransactionType",
    ChargeCode AS "Transaction/ChargeCode", 
    Description AS "Transaction/Description", 
    DebitAmount AS "Transaction/DebitAmount"
FROM #OwnerHistoryTemp
WHERE OwnerID = '11111111'
GROUP BY OwnerID, RecordID, Date, ChargeCode, Description, DebitAmount
order by OwnerID
FOR XML PATH ('OwnerID'), ROOT('OwnerHistory')
```

Returns the folowing:

```
<OwnerHistory>
    <OwnerID OwnerID="11111111">
        <Transaction RecordID="28727">
            <Date>2014-12-01</Date>
            <TransactionType>E</TransactionType>
            <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
            <Description>APPLY CHARGES</Description>
            <DebitAmount>210.0000</DebitAmount>
        </Transaction>
    </OwnerID>
    <OwnerID OwnerID="11111111">
        <Transaction RecordID="28728">
            <Date>2014-12-03</Date>
            <TransactionType>C</TransactionType>
            <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
            <Description>DB11111111</Description>
            <DebitAmount>210.0000</DebitAmount>
        </Transaction>
    </OwnerID>
    <OwnerID OwnerID="11111111">
        <Transaction RecordID="28729">
            <Date>2015-01-01</Date>
            <TransactionType>E</TransactionType>
            <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
            <Description>APPLY CHARGES</Description>
            <DebitAmount>183.3700</DebitAmount>
        </Transaction>
    </OwnerID>
</OwnerHistory>
```

Any thoughts on how to only pull the OwnerID one time as the Parent and group all transactions underneath it?

Might be something simple I'm just not understanding, or it might be impossible. Feel free to publicly cane me if the former is the case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ready for your caning?

Nest your queries to get nested XML, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  OwnerID AS "@ID",
  (SELECT
      TransactionID AS "Transaction/@ID",
      [Date] AS "Transaction/Date",
      TransactionType AS "Transaction/Type",
      ChargeCode AS "Transaction/ChargeCode",
      [Description] AS "Transaction/Description",
      DebitAmount AS "Transaction/DebitAmount"
    FROM OwnerHistory
    WHERE OwnerID = [Owner].OwnerID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) Transactions
FROM OwnerHistory [Owner]
WHERE OwnerID = '11111111' 
FOR XML PATH('Owner'), ROOT('OwnerHistory'), TYPE
```

Resulting XML:

```
<OwnerHistory>
  <Owner ID="11111111">
    <Transactions>
      <Transaction ID="28727">
        <Date>2015-03-26</Date>
        <Type>E</Type>
        <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
        <Description>APPLY CHARGES</Description>
        <DebitAmount>210.0000</DebitAmount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction ID="28728">
        <Date>2015-03-26</Date>
        <Type>C</Type>
        <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
        <Description>DB11111111</Description>
        <DebitAmount>210.0000</DebitAmount>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction ID="28729">
        <Date>2015-03-26</Date>
        <Type>E</Type>
        <ChargeCode>A1</ChargeCode>
        <Description>APPLY CHARGES</Description>
        <DebitAmount>183.3700</DebitAmount>
      </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
  </Owner>
</OwnerHistory>
```

Note that the `TOP 1` is only included to avoid repeating the entire set of transactions for each row containing the `OwnerID`. This could be handled in a number of ways; normally this sort of nesting would be the result of a join on two normalized tables so that only one instance of `Owner` would occur.

MSDN has some good [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx) to demonstrate this technique.

Comment: Hmmmmmm..... I've tried running that and tweaking it a bit. I've read the documentation as well. I'll keep playing around with it and see what I can come up with. Thanks for your response!!

Comment: @FernandoVega, sorry about that, I was answering from my phone without the benefit of a database to play with. I've updated the answer with a tested query.

Comment: Hey man!! That's fantastic!! I was so close, yet so far :'(

I really appreciate you taking the time to look into this and figure this out for me. Not only that, but educating me! 

I'm not sure where you are, but if you're ever in MN, you've got at least a 12 pack of beer waiting for you! Hell, a whole case!!

FYI i tried to upvote your solution but it wouldn't let me per not having a reputation level of 15. If/when I do, I'll try and come back to give you some points!! 

Thanks again!!!

Comment: @FernandoVega glad I could help. The system I've spent the past two years writing relies heavily on constructing XML from SQL Server, so I knew the concept but couldn't quite get the syntax without actually doing it.